# Why protobuf's `source_code_info().location_size()` is zero?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I wrote a tool to parse `.proto` file. While I use `file_proto.source_code_info().location_size()` to get the num, I always got `0`. I print the `file_proto`'s `ShortDebugString()` and it shows actually there are contents!

So what's wrong with the `location_size()`, or something I misunderstand?

The source code just like this:

```cpp
bool PbConst::CheckFileAndGetDeclarationCode(const pb::FileDescriptor *file_desc, std::string &code_block) const {
    int ret = ErrorCode::PROCESS_SUCCESS;
    pb::FileDescriptorProto file_proto;
    file_desc->CopySourceCodeInfoTo(&file_proto);
    const pb::SourceCodeInfo *src_info = &file_proto.source_code_info();

    std::cout << file_proto.ShortDebugString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "location_size: " << file_proto.source_code_info().location_size() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < src_info->location_size(); ++i) {
        const auto *loc = &src_info->location(i);
        if ((loc->path_size() == 1 && loc->path(0) == 2) ||  // import
            (loc->path_size() == 2 && loc->path(0) == 3)) {  // package
            if (!loc->leading_comments().empty()) {
                std::string src = loc->leading_comments();
                std::string attachment;
                ret = handle_common_cmd("@pbc_declare", src, attachment);
                COND_EXP(ret == ErrorCode::PROCESS_SUCCESS, std::swap(code_block, src); return true);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My protobuf's version is `3.7.0`. And the code in my project is https://github.com/Modnars/ModTools/blob/master/pbc/src/pb_const.cc

Comment: Can you share the output of printing `file_proto.ShortDebugString()`?

Comment: Oh, thx, I've just found the reason after a few tries. I didn't write correct `target_include_directories` in the `CMakeLists.txt`. And the program maybe linked wrong to my local protobuf whose version is `3.13.0`. I fixed the CMakeLists.txt using `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src" PUBLIC "${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_PATH}")` and it performed right! Thanks for your attention!